# discord.js async function catch not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, try-catch, es6-promise

I'm making a new command handler that displays a message when an error occurs while the command is running.
This is my command:

```
const simpleCommand = require("../../core/simpleCommand")

module.exports = new simpleCommand(
    async(message, args, client, addCD) => {

        message.delete()
        message.channel.send(args.join(' '))
    }, {
        name: "say",
        aliases: ["say", "talk"],
        cooldown: 0,
        cooldownMessage: "",
        perms: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_MESSAGES"],
        usage: "{prefix}{cmd} <text>",
        description: "Make 8k say something, good for roleplays :D"
    }
)
```

Basically its just a say command. Now when I just type the say command without any args it should catch the error but it doesn't and it becomes an unhandled rejection. Here is my command handler:

```
function isAO(val) {
    return val instanceof Array || val instanceof Object ? true : false;
}
//the command runs but errors arent being catched
try {
    commandobj.fn(message, args, client, addCD)
        .catch(e => {
            message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("oh noe").setDescription(`An error has occured, if this keeps coming again and again contact the owner\n\`\`\`${(isAO(e)?JSON.stringify(e):e.toString())}\`\`\``))
            message.channel.stopTyping()
        })

    message.channel.stopTyping()
} catch (e) {


    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("oh noe").setDescription(`An error has occured, if this keeps coming again and again contact the owner\n\`\`\`${(isAO(e)?JSON.stringify(e):e.toString())}\`\`\``))
    message.channel.stopTyping()
}
```

And here is my simpleCommand class:

```
module.exports = class simpleCommand {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {function(message, args, client, addCool):void} fn The command function
     * @param {Object} props Extra details for command
     * @param {Array} props.aliases Extra aliases for the command, for example 8k!shop can also be written as 8k!market
     * @param {Boolean} props.ownerOnly Sets a command to owner only
     * @param {Array} props.perms Permissions a command needs, such as attachFiles
     * @param {Number} props.cooldown cooldown ms
     * @param {String} props.cooldownMessage Message to show when cooldown is active
     * @param {String} props.description Command description showed in help page
     * @param {String} props.usage Usage for command
     * @param {String} props.name Name of command
     * @param {Boolean} props.hidden If true command will not be shown on help page
     */
    constructor(fn, props) {
        this.fn = fn
        this.passedProps = props
    }

    get props() {
        return Object.assign({
            usage: '{prefix}{command}',
            cooldown: 3000,
            ownerOnly: false,
            cooldownMessage: "This command is in cooldown try again in **{timeleft}**"
        }, this.passedProps, {
            perms: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'EMBED_LINKS'].concat(this.passedProps.perms || [])
        })
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing when catching the error or is there something else wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: afaik the issue here isn't that you have an error in your code but that the discord API sends you an error back. Thats why the `catch` doesn't do anything. What you can do is just check in your command if you have arguments and if you don't return with an error message to the user.

Comment: oh is there a way to check if the command has a discord error

Comment: you cannot check if an error will be thrown on a global scale, no. however in this case the error is because you try to send an empty message. Thats very easy to check. What you can also do is catch `unhandledRejection` errors on a local or global scale.

Comment: alright, did that, thanks!